# how to get UL LI value in jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to get ul li listbox value  in function but i cant find way.

My code is like that.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="newloc">
    <?php
    $res_add = DB::table('res_br')->where('email',$user_email->email)->get();

    if(count($res_add) != "") {
        foreach($res_add as $rr1) { 
        ?> 
            <li value="<?= $rr1->street;?>"><?= $rr1->street;?></li>
        <?php    
        }
    }
    ?>
</ul>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" onClick="buildorder()" >Build Your Order</button>
```

My jquery function is like that

```
function buildorder() {
    var radio =   $("input[name='newradio']:checked").val();
    var location = $(this).find('li');

    console.log(li.text());
    alert(radio);
    alert(location);
}
```

can some help me.to get location variable.

Comment: have you thought What `this` refers to in function `buildorder`?

Comment: Can you please show the rendered HTML and JavaScript alone please?

Comment: can you pls give the rendered output from page source in browser

Comment: `console.log(li.text())` what is li here ? I think you want to do something like `console.log(location.text());`

Comment: @ satpal buildorder() function for getting data after submit form

Comment: send `this` context in function then use `$(this).prev('ul').find('li')`

Comment: @ricky i try but its not geting value

Comment: pass `onClick="buildorder(this)"` here and get it in function argument then use that one instead.

Comment: `this` refers to the button element and not the `ul`. Since the `li` is not a child of the button element, it won't be found by the `find` function of jQuery.

Comment: i try that but still not working    var location = $(this).prev('ul').find('li');
     
     console.log(location.text());

Comment: How is your PHP even outputting HTML without an `echo` or `print`?

Comment: @ Mouser  echo  can print value

Comment: @ Mouser <?=  its means in php its echo..otherwise you have to type <?php echo both are same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's fix this code first:

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="newloc">
 <?php
     $res_add = DB::table('res_br')->where('email',$user_email->email)->get();
     if(count($res_add) != "")
     {
        foreach($res_add as $rr1)
        {   
            echo '<li value="'.$rr1->street.'">'.$rr1->street.'</li>';
        }
     }
?>
</ul>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" onClick="buildorder()" >Build Your Order</button>
```

Now your code outputs `li`-elements based upon the `foreach`.

Next the button code:

```
function buildorder()
{

      var radio =   $("input[name='newradio']:checked").val(); //this refers to an input that is not in this post, but I assume this refers to a location in the list.
      var location = $('#newloc').find('li'); //no this, let's use the id

      console.log(location.text()); //this will list all the li elements and there textContent

      alert(radio);
      alert(location);

}
```

This only fixes the code and will give you information from the `li`s. However since we don't know more about your code I can't help you further with selecting the correct `li`.

You can even assign the click handler to the button with jQuery.

```
$('button.btn.btn-primary').click(buildorder);
```

Comment: i got is error :    ReferenceError: li is not defined

Comment: @VJay, updated, `li.text()` won't work, it needs to be `location.text()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code ,hope this will help

```
$("#newloc li").click(function() {
alert(this.id); 
alert($(this).html()); 
alert($(this).text());
```

});